# Post type category in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I've got post_type = portfolio in my wordpress page, and with this code I get the category of each post:

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'portfolio_category' );

foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    $draught_links[] = $term->name;
}

$on_draught = join( ", ", $draught_links );
```

But it's not working correctly. It shows the category of current post, and of all posts before. How to fix it?

Comment: A little more context might be needed to answer this question. For instance, is this code within "The Loop" or outside of it?

Comment: and if it is within a loop consider initialising `$draught_links =array()` just before `foreach ( $terms as $term )`

Comment: @user622018 That seems like a pretty likely cause.

Comment: user622018 it's working. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this code for specific category

```
<?php
global $post;
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 5, 'category' => 3 );


$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $post ) :
setup_postdata($post); ?>

<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

Chnage the number of post and category ID....